# Does Salesforce mobile app doesn't support campaign image banner in IOS?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, chatter, mobile

I'm having trouble debugging what went wrong because the campaign banner is showing perfectly on Android but not on iOS. Is this somehow a limitation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When viewing the donation page in the Salesforce mobile application for iOS, the campaign banner is not visible, but when I switch to Android, the image banner is there.